# Python Json reference and validation

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonschema

I'm starting using python to validate some json information, i'm using a json schema with reference but i'm having trouble to reference those files. This is the `code` :

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from jsonschema import validate
import jsonref
def assert_valid_schema(data, schema_file):
    """ Checks whether the given data matches the schema """

    schema = _load_json_schema(schema_file)
    return validate(data, schema)

def _load_json_schema(filename):
    """ Loads the given schema file """

    relative_path = join('schemas', filename).replace("\\", "/")
    absolute_path = join(dirname(__file__), relative_path).replace("\\", "/")

    base_path = dirname(absolute_path)
    base_uri = 'file://{}/'.format(base_path)

    with open(absolute_path) as schema_file:
        return jsonref.loads(schema_file.read(), base_uri=base_uri, jsonschema=True, )

assert_valid_schema(data, 'grandpa.json')
```

The `json` data is :

```
data = {"id":1,"work":{"id":10,"name":"Miroirs","composer":{"id":100,"name":"Maurice Ravel","functions":["Composer"]}},"recording_artists":[{"id":101,"name":"Alexandre Tharaud","functions":["Piano"]},{"id":102,"name":"Jean-Martial Golaz","functions":["Engineer","Producer"]}]}
```

And i'm saving the schema and reference file, into a **schemas** folder :

**recording.json :**

```
{"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#","title":"Schema for a recording","type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"number"},"work":{"type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"number"},"name":{"type":"string"},"composer":{"$ref":"artist.json"}}},"recording_artists":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"artist.json"}}},"required":["id","work","recording_artists"]}
```

**artist.json :**

```
{"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#","title":"Schema for an artist","type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"number"},"name":{"type":"string"},"functions":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"}}},"required":["id","name","functions"]}
```

And this is my `error` :

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.5281.24)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\proxytypes.py", line 207, in __subject__
    return self.cache
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\proxytypes.py", line 131, in __getattribute__
    return _oga(self, attr)
AttributeError: 'JsonRef' object has no attribute 'cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\jsonref.py", line 163, in callback
    base_doc = self.loader(uri)
<MORE>
```

python version : 3.6.5

windows 7

Ide : intellijIdea

Can somebody help me?
Thank you

Comment: I can't provide an answer as I'm not familiar with this implementation, but a JSON Schema is not aware of where its file is located, so an implementation will not by default know how to resolve those references! You may just need to set the `$id` of the schema, or you may need to add the schemas to the libraries instance using an API. There's not much documentation about how to do this with that implementation: https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/

Comment: I'll nudge some people on the slack to come and take a look =]

Comment: Version 0.2 of the jsonref library might be broken/incompatible in some strange way. Try `pip install jsonref==0.1`...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why, but on Windows, the `file://` needs an extra `/`. So the following change should do the trick

```
base_uri = 'file:///{}/'.format(base_path)
```

Arrived at this answer from a solution posted for a related [issue](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/98#issuecomment-105475109) in json schema